# Return the next line of a csv file each time a php script is called

Tags: php, jquery, json, csv, highcharts

I am using highcharts to create a "live" chart with dynamically updating data. It calls a php file which is supposed to parse a CSV and output the result as json.

My Highcharts/jQuery Code is this:

```
function requestData() {
    $.ajax({
        url: 'datatest.php',
        success: function(point) {
            var series = chart.series[0],
                shift = series.data.length > 20; // shift if the series is longer than 20

            // add the point
            chart.series[0].addPoint(eval(point), true, shift);

            // call it again after one second
            setTimeout(requestData, 10000); 
        },
        cache: false
    });
}
```

My datatest.php file is thus:

```
<?php 

header("Content-type: text/json");

$handle = fopen("WindSpeed.csv", "r");

$windVals = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ",");

$x = time() * 1000;

$y = $windVals[0];

// Create a PHP array and echo it as JSON
$ret = array($x, $y);
echo json_encode($ret);

?>
```

However, I can't figure out how to pass the next line of the csv each time the php script is called; it constantly passes the same json values (in the first line of the csv) to highcharts so it just shows a flat straight line.

I'm extremely new to this, but is there a way to parse the next line of the CSV file every time the PHP script is called? Or is there a better alternative way of doing this?

Thanks,

Regards,
Kev

Comment: why don't you use a counter on the ajax function that each time the function is triggered increase by one. You pass it as a parameter to datatest.php and use it to skip as many csv lines as already read?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I'm not great with JavaScript and don't fully remember the scoping rules for what you posted, so here is PHP. Something like this should work by storing the line in the session and increment it each time the script is called.  This uses `file()` to read all lines into an array:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['line'] = isset($_SESSION['line']) ? ++$_SESSION['line'] : 0;

$lines = file('WindSpeed.csv');

if(isset($lines[$_SESSION['line']])) {
    $windVals = str_getcsv($lines[$_SESSION['line']], ',');
} else {
    $_SESSION['line'] = 0;
}

header("Content-type: text/json");
$x = time() * 1000;
$y = $windVals[0];
$ret = array($x, $y);
echo json_encode($ret);
```

If the file is large you might want to loop through it using `fgetcsv()` until you reach the proper line.  Something like:

```
session_start();
$_SESSION['line'] = isset($_SESSION['line']) ? ++$_SESSION['line'] : 0;

$handle = fopen('WindSpeed.csv', 'r');

$i = 0;
while(($windVals = fgetcsv($handle, 1000, ',')) && $i <= $_SESSION['line']) {
    $i++;
}
if(!$windVals) {
    $_SESSION['line'] = 0;
}

header("Content-type: text/json");
$x = time() * 1000;
$y = $windVals[0];
$ret = array($x, $y);
echo json_encode($ret);
```

Comment: Brilliant, that worked perfectly, cheers! The only change I had to make was $_SESSION['line']++ to ++$_SESSION['line'], to increment line and then return it, rather than returning THEN incrementing - the latter way it kept it never incremented across sessions.

Comment: Just to add - I had to use $y = (float)$windVals[0], as it was returning a string which Highcharts couldn't read.